# Using a matrix to find a 45 degree rotation of a function

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

[image: mat]

I have no idea how to start the question, I've looked at the solution but it is just the 45 degree CCW rotation matrix and I can't figure out how to arrive there.

Comment: $u^2-v^2$ is a difference of squares. Can you guess $x(u,v)$ and $y(u,v)$ such that $2xy = u^2-v^2$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Note that\begin{align}q(au+bv,cu+dv)&=2(au+bv)(cu+dv)\\&=2acu^2+2(ad+bc)uv+2bdv^2\end{align}and therefore you want to have$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}2ac=1\\ad+bc=0\\2bd=-1\end{array}\right.$$and it turns out that one solution of this system is $a=c=d=\frac1{\sqrt2}$ and $b=-\frac1{\sqrt2}$. But the matrix$$\begin{bmatrix}\frac1{\sqrt2}&-\frac1{\sqrt2}\\\frac1{\sqrt2}&\frac1{\sqrt2}\end{bmatrix}$$is the matrix of a $45^\circ$ degree rotation around the origin.